# Unable to start program 'DTS' OLE has sent a request and is waiting for a reply?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

> when we are trying to load huge data from excel file using ssis we are getting this
>   error  ole has sent a request and is waiting for a reply in ssis.

**Anyone have any idea??**

Answer (score 0):

The solution I got is apply

> Delay Validation = true

on the package level to avoid the above error.